# Setting CacheDuration on a WebMethod from web.config?

Tags: asp.net, web-services, asp.net-4.0

For an ASP.Net Webservice, I would like to be able to set the CacheDuration for either all webmethods or indivdual webmethods in web.config, so it can be adjusted without recompiling the solution.

```
[WebMethod(CacheDuration=60)]
```

Can it be done? How?

Comment: saving value in AppSettings maybe?

Comment: The problem is not saving the value, the problem is applying the value to the webmethod.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not seem to be possible.

Answer (score -1):

**VB**

```
Public Class Service1
    Inherits System.Web.Services.WebService
    <System.Web.Services.WebMethod(CacheDuration:=60)> _
    Public Function ConvertTemperature(ByVal dFahrenheit As Double) _
                                       As Double
        ConvertTemperature = ((dFahrenheit - 32) * 5) / 9
    End Function
End Class
```

**C#**

```
public class Service1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
{ 
    [System.Web.Services.WebMethod(CacheDuration=60)]
    public double ConvertTemperature(double dFahrenheit)
    {
       return ((dFahrenheit - 32) * 5) / 9;
    }
}
```

Source : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/byxd99hx%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: This shows how to set the cache duration by using an attribute value in code, as I already did in my question. I want to do it from web.config